# Return an array without creating a variable

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

I have the following C# method:

```
private string[] test()
{
}
```

I would like to know if I can do something like this within the method:

```
return {"1","2"}
```

instead of:

```
string[] quantity = { "1","2" };
return quantity;
```

Kindly let me know how I can do this in C#.

Comment: Even if it could be done (no, it can't) I'm fairly sure there would be no difference in memory usage. What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: While a serious question the compiler should the same optimised code for both situation. So you're just saving a couple a characters in a test method. Not something I would do for production code (hard coded array's anyway). And I can see a situation in the future you'll need that local variable anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return new string[] { "1", "2" };
```

Answer (score 4):

The **shortest** way:

```
return new[] { "1", "2" };
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean:

```
private string[] test()
{
    return new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
}
```